# Как реализовать различные представления одной сущности в веб-приложении

Tags: java, веб-программирование

В веб-приложении есть много различных сущностей, которые взаимодействуют между собой. Примером такой сущности может быть "пользователь".

В разных частях приложения для работы требуется разный набор полей пользователя. Например, на странице редактирования пользователя требуются все поля, на странице с историей входов пользователя нужны только идентификатор, название и дата последнего входа.

Если создать один класс для пользователя в приложении, то будет лишний расход ресурсов на хранение лишний полей, их заполнение и пр. Особенно это актуально, если нужно сериализовать объект в json для передачи браузеру (это делается автоматически и лишние поля создают значительный трафик).

Если создавать разные классы для разных частей приложения, то получается большое дублирование кода; много классов для одной сущности, которые тяжело поддерживать; приходится писать дополнительные дао - всё очень неудобно и как-то неправильно.

Какие подходы существуют для поддержки в приложении разных представлений одной и той же сущности в разных частях приложения?

Comment: Сейчас в приложении используются Struts и самописные DAO-классы. Struts выполняет сериализацию в JSON со всей иерархией, что создаёт много проблем. Плюс DAO по дефолту выгружает из базы максимум необходимой информации для заполнении объекта, что тоже не айс.

Comment: не уверен, но кажется вы занимаетесь преждевременной оптимизацией. Неужели у вас у пользователя такое сумасшедшее количество полей что это сильно влияет на ресурсы?

Comment: Попробуйте подойти к этому стандарным путем - настройте кеш, добавьте ленивую инциализацию для связанных с пользователем сущностей. Для передачи определенных полей можно использовать DTO.

Comment: Пользователь - это только пример. Есть другие сущности, полей в которых много плюс вложенные сущности. Уже сейчас элементарные запросы к серверу возвращают ответ по 100-200 килобайт за счёт лишних полей, да и время сериализации существенно. Не хочется себе свинью сразу подкладывать.

Comment: Тогда попробуйте ограничить количество инфы с помощью DTO'шек и ленивой инициализации связей между сущностями, что бы не тянуть лишнюю инфу из базы во время сериализации.

Не уверен чем у вас выполняется сериализация в json, но например у Jackson'a можно выполнять фильтрацию сериализуемых полей для конкретного контроллера.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, попробую копать в сторону DTO и фильтрации во время сериализации.